# mysql_query return error on submit

Tags: mysql

```
define('DB_NAME','swiftx');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','123456');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}else{
    echo("Database Connected");
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['attendance'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO people (Name,Email) VALUES ('$value','$value2')";

if(!mysqli_query($sql)){
    die ("ERROR:". mysqli_error()); //error here <<<<<<<<
}

}
mysqli_close($connection);
```

why is mysql returing error `"mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters"`
i am following a website tutorial , i double check again and again , i have done noting wrong , can anyone help me fix it ? i have no idea what i doing wrong.

Comment: can you show your `people` table structure please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mysqli_query() we need to pass two parameters

1. $query
2. $link_identifier

in your case $query is $sql and $link_identifier is $connection..it mean you need to use mysqli_qeury() in this way 
**mysqli_query($sql, $connection)**

Answer (score 0):

Your error `"mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters"` is pretty self-explanatory. It expects **two** parameters you are giving just one.

Try this:

```
if(!mysqli_query( $connection, $sql) ){
```

Comment: paramters for mysqli_query which you given should be in revers order means first $sql and then $connection

Comment: thank you ~ but the tutorial using one still can get thought it. so werid i think maybe he is mysql.